# Reading from azure IoT endpoint

Tags: azure, arduino, iot, azure-iot-hub, endpoints

I have a little IoT project with one device. Arduino sends some values to azure where function application processes them and sends instructions for arduino to the endpoint in IoT hub. *(/devices/MKR1000/messages/devicebound?api-version=2016-02-03)*
I need to get data from this endpoint in real time so I want arduino to read only the last (the newest) message every time, but it starts from the oldest.

It's possible to make the arduino read all the messages from the endpoint and than show the last, but I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Thank you.

Comment: do you need to discard the old messages and process only the last?

Comment: Yes,  exactly.  .

Comment: If you are interested only on the latest information "sent" from the cloud application, you could consider using device twins instead of messages. It's a declarative pattern, so you would use it to express the desired state of your device (as opposed to invoke a command or send a message). Device twin changes can be listened to using a pub sub model, registering a callback, and on change you would read the device twin to see the new "desired" state.

Comment: @Openzz, What's the device protocol? In the case of the MQTT or AMQP protocols, using the device direct methods can help to handle a real-time communication between the cloud-backend and device.

Answer (score 0):

You receive old messages because they are still queued in Azure IoT Hub due to the device not "complete" these messages. [***IoT Hub supports the option to complete/reject/abandon C2D messages over HTTPS and AMQP only at the moment.***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/8d0f1f14cee839aa72c0f82dd6f4c6576352dd9e/readme.md)

Another option is setting ExpiryTimeUtc(in function application?) to release older messages faster(Minimum 1 minute. Default: 1 hour.).

More information you can reference "[Send cloud-to-device messages from IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d)".